# Parse: How to reset the local datastore?

Tags: parse-platform, local-datastore

For testing purposes I used the Parse local datastore with synchronous methods and got, as expected, the *Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread*.
My app had also several bugs that let it crash. I fixed the bugs and replaced the synchronous methods by asynchronous methods.

However the app now has unexpected errors:

When `[Parse enableLocalDatastore];` is executed, I get again the *Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread*, although no synchronous method has been called yet.

When I then execute

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
NSArray *allUsers = [query findObjects];
```

I get the error *-[__NSCFDictionary fetchFromLocalDatastoreInBackground]: unrecognized selector sent to instance xxxxxxx*.

Apparently, these errors are related to earlier crashes of the app, and the local datastore might be in an inconsistent state.

My question is: **Is it possible to reset the local datastore to avoid errors related to earlier runs?**

Comment: i get same warning message if i enable local data store in `appdelegate.m` file. did you find any solution?

Comment: Not a solution, but a workaround: When the app is deleted from the simulator or device, the local datastore is also deleted, and one can start from scratch again (see my own answer below).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my silly question: One simply has to delete the app from the simulator or the device. This deleted the local datastore.